# Logical anding two boolean arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

What would be a nice elegant functional solution for anding two boolean arrays in ES6?

```
const a1 = [true, false, false]
const a2 = [true, true, false]
```

should result in:

```
[true, false, false]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the 1st array, and get the value of the 2nd array using the index (the 2nd param in the callback):

```js
const a1 = [true, false, false]
const a2 = [true, true, false]

const result = a1.map((b, i) => b && a2[i]);

console.log(result);
```